# Android Step Counter -- Count does not match either fitbit / Samsung Step Counter. (Off by thousands)

Tags: android, service

The problem I'm having is that my count is totally off, from any pedometers, fitbit, or the Samsung Step Counter.

It appears to shut down, and not add any steps after awhile. 
If I enter that  I'm starting at 3000 for example, it calculates an offset and it stores as a shared preference.  It tries to remain registered for the the Sensor.  I also store the current steps, so that if the activity that is listening for Step Broadcasts is resumed, it will request for the steps to be output.

I have tried making the service provide notifications and be a foreground service, but the accuracy does not improve, and it uses a ton of power, I have tried a wakelock, with similiar results, not accurate, and uses too much power.

As it stands, my app does not show up in the power usage statistics, so it is hardly using power at all.  The hardware sensor should be capturing steps from the accelerometers, and when it does wake up, it should output the newest steps.  When it does update, it is closer to the value that I set as the step count.

I am using the Step Counter which was made available in kitkat or above, on some devices.  The following code registers for the sensor.

```
Sensor sensor =  sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    if (null != sensor)
    {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor,
SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
```

This is within the OnCreate Method of a Service, that I have constructed.
  The Service is created as sticky.  And uses a broadcast receiver to receive starting steps from an activity, to compute an offset.  It also broadcasts the steps that have happened.  Here is more of the code.

```
class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_REQUEST_STEPS))
        {
            SendStepBroadcast(currentSteps);
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SET_STEPS))
        {
            setSteps = intent.getFloatExtra(
                    STEPS_OCCURRED, -1);
            SendStepBroadcast(setSteps);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (setSteps > -1) {
        offset = setSteps - event.values[0] + 1;
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.halfwaythere", 
MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putFloat("offset", offset).apply();
        setSteps = -1;
    }
    currentSteps = event.values[0] + offset;
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.halfwaythere",
 MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putFloat("currentSteps", currentSteps).apply();
    SendStepBroadcast(currentSteps);
}

private void SendStepBroadcast(float steps) {
    Intent broadcastSteps = new Intent();
    broadcastSteps.setAction(ACTION_STEPS_OCCURRED);
    broadcastSteps.putExtra(STEPS_OCCURRED, steps);
    this.sendBroadcast(broadcastSteps);
 }
```

In the Activity the following code is used to start the service:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StepService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

My most recent set of attempts to fix this, I tried the following:

- Use android:process=":background" to start the service in it's own process.  I will try this tomorrow in a field test, and see how it works.
- I tried setting the count to zero, and found out my code would not allow, so in the above code I used > -1. Since -1 shouldn't be a valid step count.
- All of the code above has test wrapped around it, and I've tried to find any edge cases, and have looked over stack overflow for pedometer problems with Step Counter on Samsung Galaxy S4.  Or anything about best practices.

Thanks, and if you need any additional info, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research:

- When the screen is locked, the Hardware Sensor waits before outputting steps.  It does count steps, but once you press the button on the side it wakes up, and it receives a SensorEvent.
- Service was occasionally having Start Command being called.  Was very important that I only register once, so I added a boolean that would be flipped once the initialization was called, and flip off after that.  Service was paused, but not killed, and Start Command would run upon it being awoken.
- Setting Service to Foreground, seems to be getting closer to the value from other pedometers.  Uses more battery, but is keeping it going more, so that makes sense.
- Did not require wakelock, it was only on for several milliseconds, but that did not cause the hardware sensor to send results.
- Will have my Service run till goal is achieved, or offer the option to stop tracking at half way point.  I really just wanted something to tell me that I would get my goal if I turned around, anything else will be equivalent to extra steps.

So I will apply what I found and continue on with my app, should be on the App Store by mid July.

Comment: So using the accelerometer, and interpreting it, is giving me much closer values, and is using less battery than wakelock, or service to foreground.  And is giving me updates even when the screen is locked, and in my pocket.  The Hardware Step Counter does not output anything during screen off, to save power most likely.  So accelerometer is the way to go for me.

Comment: I am facing same problem. so did you resolve this issue? if yes can you share code..